# Android no puede modificar un textview

Tags: android

Tengo un TextView que no se actualiza en tiempo de ejecución. Dicho TextView está definido por el siguiente codigo en XML:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/agi_val"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView" />
```

En el código de la actividad, accedo al TextView de esta forma:

```
private TextView AGI;
///< Some stuff

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abf__char_gen__basic_info);

        abfToolsSaveData = (ABFToolsSaveData) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("SaveDataClass");

        this.AGI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agi_val);
        ///< Some stuff

        if (abfToolsSaveData != null) {
            this.chargeData(true);
        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "abfToolsSaveData is null");
        }
    }
```

Y en chargeData(boolean):

```
public void chargeData(boolean firstTime){
        if(firstTime){
            MainCharacteristics mc = abfToolsSaveData.getCharacter().getMainCharacteristics(); ///< We get the main characteristics, auto-generated the first time

            /**
             * Set the Text Views with the default value
             */
            if(AGI != null){    ///< I've done this to check if the text view is null or not
                Log.d("INFO", String.valueOf(AGI));
                AGI.setText(mc.getAGI());
            }
            else
                Log.d("INFO","AGI IS NULL");
            ///< Some stuff
        }
    }
```

La cosa es que "agi_val" lo encuentra, pero el TextView AGI de la actividad, no puede accerder al recurso agi_val. El log del error es el siguiente:

```
///< Esta primera linea es mi salida por pantalla que demuestra que AGI tiene acceso a agi_val:
    09-20 10:07:32.344 1266-1266/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion D/INFO: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b670993 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0077 app:id/agi_val}
    09-20 10:07:32.344 1266-1266/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000009
    --------- beginning of crash
    09-20 10:07:32.347 1266-1266/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion, PID: 1266
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion.ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
///< Esta linea referencia a la asignación del texto
    at com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion.ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.chargeData(ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.java:73)
    at com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion.ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.onCreate(ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Alguien sabe que esta sucediendo? He probado a hacer un Clean y Rebuild, a reiniciar el programa, y muchas otras cosas que he encontrado por internet, pero nada me da la solución al problema.

Comment: El xml donde defines la vista en la que está el textview es layout.activity_abf__char_gen__basic_info???

Comment: Un saludo @SliferDragon, antes de realizar una pregunta **puedes buscar en el sitio, puedes encontrar información acerca de este problema ya que se ha preguntado con anterioridad** https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+String+resource+ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estoy casi seguro que el metodo `mc.getAGI()` returna un `int` por lo que muestra el stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
```

Lo que el error quiere decir es que estas utilizando la sobrecarga `setText(int resourceId)` que busca el recurso R.string que tenga el id que retorna el metodo `getAGI()` y lo mas seguro es que quieres imprimir el valor de retorno, no buscar un recurso `R.string`.

Convierte el valor de retorno a `String` para que funcione:

```
if(AGI != null){
    ///< I've done this to check if the text view is null or not
    Log.d("INFO", String.valueOf(AGI));
    String agi = String.valueOf(mc.getAGI());
    AGI.setText(agi);
}
```